# I can't install anything anymore because of linux-image errors

Tags: apt

I'm trying to install the spotify client on Ubuntu 16.04 but I keep getting the following error. 
I followed the instructions here: https://www.spotify.com/uk/download/linux/
 Same happens when I try to update mongodb for example. Any suggestions ?

```
 Reading package lists... Done
    Building dependency tree       
    Reading state information... Done
    The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
      linux-headers-4.4.0-36 linux-headers-4.4.0-36-generic linux-image-4.4.0-36-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-36-generic ubuntu-core-launcher
    Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
    Recommended packages:
      libavcodec54 | libavcodec-extra-54 libavformat54
    The following packages will be REMOVED:
      linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
      linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      spotify-client
    0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 6 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    15 not fully installed or removed.
    Need to get 0 B/73,2 MB of archives.
    After this operation, 486 MB disk space will be freed.
    Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
    (Reading database ... 300801 files and directories currently installed.)
    Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
    depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-28-generic cannot be found.
    Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-28-generic package,
    or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
    WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic
    Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
    depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic: No such file or directory
    depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_VAlZ4z/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_VAlZ4z/lib/modules/4.4.0-28-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1): not found
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
     subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
    Removing linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (4.4.0-28.47) ...
    Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-28-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-28-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-28-generic
    /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1): not found
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
    Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic.postrm line 328.
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic (--remove):
     subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
    Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic (4.4.0-31.50) ...
    depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-31-generic: No such file or directory
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-31-generic cannot be found.
    Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic package,
    or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
    WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic
    Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
    depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic: No such file or directory
    depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_abdXZQ/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_abdXZQ/lib/modules/4.4.0-31-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1): not found
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic (--remove):
     subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
    Removing linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic (4.4.0-31.50) ...
    Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-31-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-31-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-31-generic
    /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1): not found
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
    Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic.postrm line 328.
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic (--remove):
     subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  Removing linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic (4.4.0-34.53) ...
    depmod: FATAL: could not load /boot/System.map-4.4.0-34-generic: No such file or directory
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/apt-auto-removal 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/dkms 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    Error! Your kernel headers for kernel 4.4.0-34-generic cannot be found.
    Please install the linux-headers-4.4.0-34-generic package,
    or use the --kernelsourcedir option to tell DKMS where it's located
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
    WARNING: missing /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic
    Ensure all necessary drivers are built into the linux image!
    depmod: ERROR: could not open directory /lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic: No such file or directory
    depmod: FATAL: could not search modules: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_4FQUrq/lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/modules.order: No such file or directory
    depmod: WARNING: could not open /var/tmp/mkinitramfs_4FQUrq/lib/modules/4.4.0-34-generic/modules.builtin: No such file or directory
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/pm-utils 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/unattended-upgrades 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/update-notifier 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1): not found
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postinst.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic (--remove):
     subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  Removing linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic (4.4.0-34.53) ...
    Examining /etc/kernel/postrm.d .
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.4.0-34-generic
    run-parts: executing /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub 4.4.0-34-generic /boot/vmlinuz-4.4.0-34-generic
    /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 6: /etc/default/grub: Windows 10 (loader) (on /dev/sda1): not found
    run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
    Failed to process /etc/kernel/postrm.d at /var/lib/dpkg/info/linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic.postrm line 328.
    dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic (--remove):
     subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
    No apport report written because MaxReports is reached already
                                                                  Errors were encountered while processing:
     linux-image-extra-4.4.0-28-generic
     linux-image-4.4.0-28-generic
     linux-image-extra-4.4.0-31-generic
     linux-image-4.4.0-31-generic
     linux-image-extra-4.4.0-34-generic
     linux-image-4.4.0-34-generic
    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Don't know what you did but you have deleted some files from the `/boot` folder see if this link can [help](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/13654/i-deleted-files-from-my-linux-boxs-boot-directory-and-now-it-wont-boot)

Comment: I'm going to try to re-install grup2 then. Hopefully that's not going to mess with loading the Windows partition.

Comment: if done right it shouldn't.